# one-category error allowed in libsvm matlab

Tags: matlab

I read an article about age and gender recognition and it says: "For age, the classifier is correct 38% of the time, and if a one-category error is allowed, the performance is 71%.".

I don't know how to do the "one-category error" with libsvm for multiclass. 
Do i have to modify the code:

```
model = svmtrain(train_label, train, ['-c ' num2str(best_C) ' -g ' num2str(best_gamma) ' -b 1']);
[predict_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(test_label, test, model, '-b 1 -q');
```

or do I have to write another code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this would be to do some post processing on the predicted labels.

Standard accuracy works something like this:

```
correct = predicted_label == test_label;
num_correct = length(find(correct));
accuracy = correct ./ length(test_label);
```

So do allow for a one category error (i.e.: for the classifier to predict the age as either one category older, or one category younger and still have it count as correct) you would need to modify what counts as correct.  Perhaps using something like:

```
correct = abs(predicted_label - test_label) <= 1;
```